# How do I eliminate the spaces between my vectors?

Tags: align

I'm trying to output a nice list of vectors. Here is my code:

```
\begin{align}
  v_{1}&=\begin{bmatrix}
           1\\
           0\\
           \vdots\\
           0     
          \end{bmatrix},
  &v_{2}&=\begin{bmatrix}
           0\\
           z_{x}\\
           \vdots\\
           0     
          \end{bmatrix},
  &v_{3}&=\begin{bmatrix}
           0\\
           0\\
           z^*_{x}\\
           \vdots\\
           0     
          \end{bmatrix},
  &\dots,&v_{N}=\begin{bmatrix}
           0\\
           0\\
           \vdots\\
           z^{*N}_{y}     
          \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
```

Unfortunately, there is too much space between each vector. [image]

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Here's what I want it more to look like:
[image]

Suggested change:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    v_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}
           1\\
           0\\
           \vdots\\
           0     
          \end{bmatrix}, \quad
    v_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}
           0\\
           z_{x}\\
           \vdots\\
           0     
          \end{bmatrix}, \quad
  v_{3}=\begin{bmatrix}
           0\\
           0\\
           z^*_{x}\\
           \vdots\\
           0     
          \end{bmatrix}, \quad
  \dots v_{N}=\begin{bmatrix}
           0\\
           0\\
           \vdots\\
           z^{*N}_{y}     
          \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

<s>This is still giving me errors though.</s>

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are experiencing the effects of using align. Which alignment are you aiming at?

Comment: @TeXnician I am trying to have all of these vectors spaced 'regularly' in the center of the page

Comment: Just work with `\[...\]` instead of align and separate the vectors by `\quad`s to get a vector space without too much space. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Thank you for your suggestion; would you be able to edit what I added to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for `align` here; it naturally spreads out elements across the text width at every (second) alignment point `&`. A regular display math environment `\[`...`\]` suffices. If you wish to have the content align vertically as well, perhaps consider using the same number of elements in each vector.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0
  \end{bmatrix}, \quad
  v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\ z_x \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0
  \end{bmatrix}, \quad
  v_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\ 0 \\ z^*_x \\ \vdots \\ 0
  \end{bmatrix}, \quad
  \dots, \quad
  v_N = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ z^{*N}_y
  \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```